# Typescript using constructor in a class won't allow for new keyword

Tags: angular, typescript, constructor

I want to be able to new up my Menu Class but I cannot when using a constructor, why is this?

```
model = new Menu();
```

So that I can then set each property

```
this.model.AppGroupID = UserID;
```

component:

```
import { Menu } from '../../models/menu-model';

model = new Menu();

let UserID = params['UserID'];
this.model.AppGroupID = UserID;
```

ABOVE works fine when NOT using constructor

menu-model.ts file

```
export class Menu {
   UserID: number;
   AppID: number;
   NavAppID: number;
   AppGroupID: number;
   SelectedCaseID: number;
   SelectedRoleID: number;
}
```

so that above works fine
but why and how could i use a constructor for this?  any benefit?

```
export class Menu {
    constructor(
        public UserID: number,
        public AppID: number,
        public NavAppID: number,
        public AppGroupID: number,
        public SelectedCaseID: number,
        public SelectedRoleID: number
    ) { }

}
```

Comment: If you define a constructor with parameters you need to provide arguments for those parameters when you call the constructor?

Comment: Did you try reading the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing a couple of different concepts I think.

This:

```
export class Menu {
   UserID: number;
   AppID: number;
   NavAppID: number;
   AppGroupID: number;
   SelectedCaseID: number;
   SelectedRoleID: number;
}
```

is basically the same as this:

```
export class Menu {

    constructor(
    ) { }

   UserID: number;
   AppID: number;
   NavAppID: number;
   AppGroupID: number;
   SelectedCaseID: number;
   SelectedRoleID: number;
}
```

i.e. if you don't specify a constructor it's basically the same as an empty constructor (I say basically as it's slightly different if you are extending a base class).

However this:

```
export class Menu {
    constructor(
        public UserID: number,
        public AppID: number,
        public NavAppID: number,
        public AppGroupID: number,
        public SelectedCaseID: number,
        public SelectedRoleID: number
    ) { }
}
```

Is different. If you define a constructor with parameters you need to provide arguments for those parameters when you call the constructor.

Because you declare the constructor parameters as "public" that also makes them properties of the class.

This is perhaps what is confusing? You don't need to create these properties in the constructor, that is just a convenient shorthand.

If don't want to specify the arguments in the constructor call don't make them parameters of the constructor, and instead declare them directly in the class body as in your first example.

Comment: am i not able to do `model = new Menu();` with the constructor with public?  so how could i set these properties    `this.model.AppGroupID = UserID;`  ?

Comment: Yes you can't do model = new Menu(). You would set properties directly instead. Don't confuse having a constructor with having public constructor parameters - they are 2 very different things. You can have one without the other.